# Why Batch File wouldn't remain variable if I redirect to it instead of call it

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, pipeline, io-redirection

I wanna implementate OutTo.cmd
which can achieve:

```
echo msg | OutTo.cmd var
echo %var%
msg
```

my code in OutTo.cmd:

```
set /p %1=

@REM For check
echo %var%
```

when I run
`echo msg | OutTo.cmd var`,
Console would display

```
msg
```

which means "msg" save into var successfully during OutTo.cmd running

but then I run
`echo %var%`, console display nothing, which means var is not defined, after OutTo.cmd

But if I run OutTo.cmd as below:

```
OutTo.cmd var
```

and type in:

```
msg
```

after OutTo.cmd finished, var's value would remain:

```
echo %var%
```

display

```
msg
```

will, I know the easiest way is:

```
echo msg > tmp
set /p newvar=<tmp
```

So I just curious about, why batch would remain variable if I call it
but not if I redirect output to it?

Comment: Correct usage in calling script is `Call foo.bat Argument1 "Argument 2" Argument3`.   In `foo.bat` the values passed to it will be available in `%1` (`Argument1`), `%2` (`"Argument 2"`), `%3` (`Argument3`) and `%*` (`Argument1 "Argument 2" Argument3`).  They can be used in `foo.bat` like `echo %1`

Comment: Maybe I didn't express clearly, sorry for my bad english, I mean batch file would remain variable if I just run it, but not also if I make output redirect to it

Comment: A pipe initiates new `cmd.exe` instances for either side, so any variables set there are lost afterwards (in the initial hosting `cmd.exe` instance)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Test.cmd
echo !cmdcmdline!

echo Call OutTo.cmd
call OutTo.cmd

echo Pipe to OutTo.cmd
echo msg | OutTo.cmd

echo Pipe to OutTo.cmd using call
echo msg | call OutTo.cmd
```

OutTo.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo(!cmdcmdline!
```

Output:

> ```
> Test.cmd
> cmd  /c Test.cmd
> Call OutTo.cmd
> cmd  /c Test.cmd
> Pipe to OutTo.cmd
> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" OutTo.cmd"
> Pipe to OutTo.cmd using call
> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" call OutTo.cmd"
> ```

This example is to display what is happening with piping and not piping.

Command used to execute Test.cmd:

> ```
> cmd /c Test.cmd
> ```

Used `enabledelayedexpansion` so that echo of `!cmdcmdline!` does not cause problems if `&` or other unquoted special character is in the command line.

About the output:

- The 1st command line is from Test.cmd itself.
- The 2nd command line is `call` OutTo.cmd from Test.cmd. Same as the 1st as same process.
- The 3rd command line is piping to OutTo.cmd. Not the same process as 1st and 2nd, it is a child process.
- The 4th command line is piping to OutTo.cmd by use of `call`. Not the same process as 1st and 2nd, it is a child process.

The 3rd and 4th will strip the outer quotes from the command after `/c` as `/S` is used and autorun commands are disabled as `/D` is used.

The 4th is obsolete as using `call` after `/c` is not required. It is executed as a separate instance of cmd.exe.

The pipe causes a separate process as piping is one process piping to another process. cmd.exe is executed to run OutTo.cmd as a child process to be piped to.

A child process can inherit from a parent process. A parent process cannot inherit from a child process. The last statement is why you cannot get `%var%` with a value set in the OP as you are trying to get it from a child process.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly explanation let me understand, thanks for your anwser. So the reason is: direct call/run .cmd is run in current process, and pipe to .cmd is child process.